# Plateaus in Quantum Hall Effect and its Robustness

Tags: condensed-matter, schroedinger-equation, quantum-hall-effect

I was studying Quantum Hall Effect and there I came out with a question that why the plateaus in the plot of Hall Resistivity are robust ?

I know by solving Schrodinger equation and using Landau Gauge Condition we can arrive at the conclusion of landau levels, but I am not satisfied that why the plateaus are robust ?

Comment: I would imagine this is discussed in most textbook treatments of the integer quantum Hall effect. The discovery of this robustness is what started the study of topological states in condensed matter physics, and the robustness is linked to a topological (TKNN) invariant that only changes in integer steps.

Comment: can you kindly mention the book and chapter.